Next.js 14 Hide Root layout in another page
I'm using app router in Next.js 14 project.
And my project folder structure is like this.
-- dashboard/
              /page.tsx      # main layout is used
              /layout.tsx
              --create
                  /page.tsx      # I want to hide main layout in this page
                  /layout.tsx

layout.tsx                # main layout, used in ALL pages
         

I should place /dashboard/create page in dashboard folder. So I think I can't move create page another folder.
How can I hide layout?

You can use Route Groups to apply different layouts without affecting the routing.
In your case it could look something like this:
.
├── (primary)/
│   ├── layout.tsx  <- formerly "main layout"
│   └── dashboard/
│       ├── layout.tsx  <- "dashboard layout"
│       └── page.tsx
└── (secondary)/
    └── dashboard/
        ├── layout.tsx  <- "dashboard layout"
        └── create/
            ├── layout.tsx  <- "dashboard create layout"
            └── page.tsx

You can ofcourse reuse a component to avoid duplication of the "dashboard layout".
Also the naming of the route groups does not matter - they should probably have a better name then "primary" and "secondary".

Thank you. The answer was really helpful.
I have one more question. I wonder if it is okay to create the same dashboard folder.
It works well, but is there a possibility that there may be a performance problem?

I'm not sure what you mean with the same dashboard folder. If you have a layout that is applied everywhere except for this one page you must use Route Groups on the first level. This shouldn't have an impact on performance.

You can separate the page in a separated folder called for ex (without-layout) and have the rest of your route inside (with-layout) with the layout.tx inside.
The folder with parenthesis is a way to separate your code without creating path.
ex:
/dashboard
  layout.tsx                # used in ALL pages
  /(without-layout)
    /create
      page.tsx
  /(with-layout)
    layout.tsx             # used in all pages inside "(with-layout)"
    ...


I am assuming by "ALL pages" OP means all pages, not just the ones under /dashboard, so this solution wouldn't work

@nyarthan in that case he can move the folder accordingly. but it's the same logic
